# How to terminate a program running from the Sublime Text 2 terminal once entering an infinite loop?

Tags: loops, sublimetext2, infinite-loop, sublimetext

Even If I close sublime the process continues to go, seeing as my laptop revs until slowing down to a crawl a few minutes later. I'm on mint linux, and can't seem to kill the process from terminal either.

Comment: There is no reason why you could not kill the process from a terminal. Can you please show the process listing using ps and tell us how you tried to kill it.

Answer (score 22):

**Execute this command:**

```
ps -A | grep sublime
```

**result Example :**

```
2547 ? 00:02:37 sublime_text
```

**You will kill process with :**

```
kill -9 2547
```

Answer (score 7):

```
killall sublime_text
```

works for me
Sublime Text 3
Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 5):

```
$ ps aux | grep Sublime
bibhas   646   0.0  4.2  3489812 177340   ??  S    Fri08PM  29:17.03 /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text 2 -psn_0_487543
$ sudo kill -9 646
```

Comment: This is happening to me also in Ubuntu. I tries to kill it with the ID like you have suggested. But still it is here. When I run ps again it is still there with same ID

Comment: I am also getting it like that. Any one have any idea how to kill it. ? because one instance is running, I am not able to open sublime again,

Answer (score 5):

on MAC:

`kill -9 $(pgrep Sublime)`

Answer (score 2):

One simple and brutal way is to just kill the process of what the program is running on. For example, if you are running a java program, then use `$killall java`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use fishshell(probably helpful for zsh) with iTerm on MAC:

```
kill -9 (pgrep Sublime)
```

Answer (score 0):

On MAC:

First of all you have to kill process and then remove all sessions

```
1) kill -9 $(pgrep Sublime)
2) sudo rm /Users/YOUR----NAME----HERE/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Local/Auto\ Save\ Session.sublime_session
```